# Android scrollView autosize

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, autoresize

I'm new to android development. I'm attempting to do something that I thought was simple but after much reading, trial and error and determination I've failed to find a solution I find simple and elegant and therefore I'm looking for help on how to approach the following:

I have two UI elemnents, a textview that reads "TextView" and an EditText box:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

The behavior I'm attempting to implement is:
As a user adds text to the EditText box it expands and grows -- at some point it grows large enough to scroll the TextView off screen. I want the TextView content to remain visible at all times. Therefore the EditText or possibly a container it lives within needs to clip it's contents instead of scrolling the entire screen.

Along with EditText I tried every possible iteration of using following elements and could not figure out a solution.

- Scrollview
- FrameLayout
- LinearLayout

If it's at all possible, I'd prefer to implement this solution in pure xml so that I can maintain good separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap `EditText` inside `ScrollView` to make it scrollable. Setting `ScrollView` `layout_weight` attribute to `1` and `fillViewport` to `true` will force ScrollView to fill available space but never push `TextView` out of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmmm...this didn't "work". As soon as I load the app and bring up the SoftKeyboard, I can visually see the edit box (which has a little yellow border) sitting behind the SoftKeyboard. True it doesn't resize but the space it's filling includes the space beneath the SoftKeyboard. I'm testing on my Galaxy 2. I found this snippet "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" to add to my application but it didn't help either. :(

Comment: Turns out I had a "Fullscreen" setting in my manifest file. Once I removed it, the implementation above worked. I also added the following to my activity: android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"

Answer (score 0):

Use `minLines` and `maxLines` (of `EditText`) to specify the minimum and maximum the `EditText` can shrink/grow to, respectively.

Comment: Yes but how will I know how many lines are available? The number of available lines changes. The variants are: If the SoftKeyboard is showing or not and screen size.