# How to anchor the Footer at the bottom of the screen in vertical orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have Activity with the header, the menu and the footer. In vertical orientation of the screen the Footer is at the bottom of the `ScrollView`, but it should be fixed at the bottom of the screen. There must be a free space between  the `ScrollView` and the Footer in vertical orientation.

How to make that the Footer be fixed at the bottom of the screen in vertical orientation?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.test.MainMenuActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorMainWhite"
    style="@style/root_layout">

    <!--- Header-->
    <include layout="@layout/content_header"/>
    <include layout="@layout/content_subheader"/>


    <!--- Menu with scroll-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/merchantInfoLayout"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_15px"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                style="@style/los_lo_merchant_info_item">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                    tools:text="test"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_32_bold_ellipsized"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                    tools:text="test"
                    style="@style/tvs_lo_text_26_ellipsized"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_1"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_1"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_2"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_2"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_3"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_3"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_4"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_4"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_5"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_5"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/los_lo_mainmenu_item">
                    <ImageView
                        style="@style/icon_default_size_center"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_6"/>
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvs_lo_text_mainmenu_button"
                        android:text="@string/title_item_6"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

     <!--- Footer-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_20px"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_20px"
            android:background="@color/colorBgLightGrey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/icon_logos_ips"
                style="@style/ips_icons_style"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try set: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: @AndersKink he's not using `RelativeLayout` so this won't work

Comment: True, did not see that

Comment: [Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505626/android-scrollview-autosize/15506253#15506253), you're missing an ``android:fillViewport="true"`` attribute on the scrollView

Comment: post an image of what is the desired outpunt please, with style attr is difficult understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @Heikki Mäenpää Nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to expand one of your upper views to fill the remaining space by setting `android:layout_weight="1"` on it. This will push your last view down to the bottom.

check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425388/2826147)

below is your layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--- Header-->
        <!--<include layout="@layout/header_layout" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--- Menu with scroll-->
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/merchantInfoLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="test" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_1" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_2" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_3" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_4" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_5" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_6" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/button8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="title_item_6" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <!--- Footer-->
        <!--<include layout="@layout/footer_layout" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="20px"
                android:paddingTop="20px">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For what the layout with the Image on above the menu?

Comment: i have not include layout but added code of that. you can change but keep height and width same

Comment: @AndrewEfremov it is working fine on my side. what issue are you facing

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
I have made some edits to your original layout. The footer will appear at
```

the bottom now and not overlap with the content of the scrollview. 
[It will appear like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0I5g.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <!--- Header-->
    <!--<include layout="@layout/header_layout" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/ll_top">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--- Menu with scroll-->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_top"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/merchantInfoLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="test" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNL2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:text="test" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_2" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_3" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_4" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_5" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_6" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_6" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="title_item_6" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!--- Footer-->
    <!--<include layout="@layout/footer_layout" />-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20px"
            android:paddingTop="20px">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I did so. Now, If I change the orientation of the screen to horizontal so that the scroll appears, then the footer will overlap the last menu item (button6).

Comment: Did you set android:id="@+id/footer", as the id of the footer layout. Because it should not overlap with everything within the scrollView because we are using android:layout_above="@+id/footer" in the scrollview.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is working, but I prefer the option from @Amit Vaghela.

Comment: Well, i am glad you found a solution. Happy Coding :)